# Copy an int array into a larger int array representing an image at a given center point

Tags: java, arrays

I have an `int[]` representing a small bitmap that I want to copy into another `int[]` representing a larger bitmap. My code thus far looks like this:

```
private int[] copyToOffsetCentered(int[] src, 
        Rectangle srcDim, int[] dest, Rectangle destDim, int dx, int dy)
{
    int startx = dx - srcDim.width / 2;
    int endx = startx + srcDim.width;
    int starty = dy - srcDim.height / 2;
    int endy = starty + srcDim.height;

    for (int x = Math.max(startx, 0); x < Math.min(endx, destDim.width); x++)
    {
        for (int y = Math.max(starty, 0); y < Math.min(endy, destDim.height); y++)
        {
            dest[y*destDim.width + x] = src[???];
        }
    }

    return dest;
}
```

The idea is that the source image array could be clipped when copied to the target array if the offset is close enough to the edge of the image. As an example, if I passed in a 2x2 source image

```
src=[1,2,3,4]
```

and a 4x4 `dest` image

```
dest=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

with `dx=0` and `dy=1`, I would expect the return array to be

```
dest=[2,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

This is due to the "edges" of the source being clipped based on the target center point.

I know that the solution is most likely pretty simple, but I am having a hard time wrapping my brain around what the math should look like to figure out the proper index I should be using for the source array inside the loops. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dx` and `dy` are the destination coordinates of the src image at the center. The row of the image is `index/Dimension.width` and the column of the image is `index%Dimension.width`.

While you're iterating the starting coordinate in the source image will be.

```
int xSrc = x - start_x;
int ySrc = y - start_y;
int srcIndex = ySrc*srcDim.getWidth() + xSrc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I have yet to test it in the code, but on paper your solution works. Thanks again for the swift reply!